# Regarding Home page

Tags: html

I hava a web application. In that i have a link called "Home". When the user clicks the starting page of the web application that is index.jsp should be displayed in the same page. How can i do that. It should work in internet explorer.

I have the following html page.

```
<html>

<body bgcolor="#FFF8DC">

<a href="index.jsp" target="parent" >HOME</a>


</body>
</html>
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Try posting the html you have again.

Comment: Yeah, your problem is unclear - post a sample an re-iterate your problem.

Comment: What does it mean by not working?

Comment: You need to claify your question a lot more.  What is the HTML of the page?  How is it being generated?

Comment: usually this is symptomatic that the OP forgot to use a code block - edited, fixed

Answer (score 4):

< a href="url">home< /a >

Answer (score 4):

**In order for your link to open in the same window it resides in, use:**

```
<a href="foo.html" target="_self">some text</a>
```

Please note the underscore before self. If you do not use it, your browser will look for a frame named "self".

Comment: The requirement is similar to  refresh button on the browser. When i click home i need the starting page of the application should be opened in the same window

Comment: I do not quite get what you mean; do you want to create a link that points people to their browser's homepage?

Answer (score 4):

See http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/special/a.html

The TARGET attribute is used with frames to specify the frame in which the link should be rendered. If no frame with such a name exists, the link is rendered in a new window unless overridden by the user. Special frame names begin with an underscore:

```
* _blank renders the link in a new, unnamed window
* _self renders the link in the current frame (useful for overriding a BASE TARGET)
* _parent renders the link in the immediate FRAMESET parent
* _top renders the link in the full, unframed window
```

In HTML 4, the TARGET attribute value is case-insensitive, so that _top and _TOP both have the same meaning. However, most browsers treat the TARGET attribute value as case-sensitive and do not recognize _TOP as having the special meaning of _top.

Comment: thanks. it is working. but will it work in IE also. I have checked in mozilla

Comment: Yes - it is a part of language specification.

Answer (score 1):

Probably is a problem addressing the jsp page. Try using the complete URL.

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing an underscore. "self" is treated as any other name label.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you intended TARGET="_parent" ? This allows a link to load in a parent frame

Answer (score 0):

```
`target="_parent"`
```

note the `_` in `_parent`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can just skip the `target` attribute of the link. Target defaults to the same browser window if you don't specify otherwise.